# How do I remove the navigation bar from a frame in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a frame in my WPF application that will hold the content of different pages.  The problem is that by default it has this ugly navigation bar at the top of the frame.  I don't want this nav bar to appear at all. How do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the NavigationUIVisibility property of the Frame to Hidden:

```
<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="Page1.xaml"/>
```